# hide div menu when clicking somewhere else

Tags: javascript, jquery

My goal is to have my div menu disappear when I click anywhere else on the page. Below is the code that opens and closes my code when clicking on the two divs themselves.

```
var content_nav = '';
var content_select = '';
window.onload=function(){
    content_nav = document.getElementById("content_nav");
    content_select = document.getElementById("content_select");
    content_nav.addEventListener("click", show_or_hide);
}

function show_or_hide()
{
   if(content_select.style.display!="block") content_select.style.display="block";
   else content_select.style.display="none";

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should listen to the click event on the whole page and hide the menu if the click was outside content_nav, try this (you might need to tweak it to make it work, I do not know your HTML):

```
$(document).click(function(e){
        if (! $(e.target).closest('#content_nav').length ) 
            $('#content_nav').hide();
    });
```

Comment: `if (! $(e.target).closest('#content_nav').length ) { ... }` will suffice !